# How do you create rows for every categories in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say that I have the following data. Like how many times my kids opened the fridge for each hour from 1 PM to 3 PM.

```
| ----- | ----- | ----- |
|  Name |  Hour |  Open |
| ----- | ----- | ----- |
|  Bob  |     1 |     4 |
| ----- | ----- | ----- |
|  Bob  |     3 |     2 |
| ----- | ----- | ----- |
|  Jane |     1 |     1 |
| ----- | ----- | ----- |
|  Jane |     2 |     7 |
| ----- | ----- | ----- |
```

If I call this with pandas, how do I fill the missing hours so I could have the following dataframe?

```
| ----- | ----- | ----- |
|  Name |  Hour |  Open |
| ----- | ----- | ----- |
|  Bob  |     1 |     4 |
| ----- | ----- | ----- |
|  Bob  |     2 |  None |    <<-- New row with Null or 0 for 'Open' column.
| ----- | ----- | ----- |
|  Bob  |     3 |     2 |
| ----- | ----- | ----- |
|  Jane |     1 |     1 |
| ----- | ----- | ----- |
|  Jane |     2 |     7 |
| ----- | ----- | ----- |
|  Jane |     3 |  None |    <<-- New row with Null or 0 for 'Open' column.
| ----- | ----- | ----- |
```

Obviously, I kinda need it to be automatic so I could use it for some real data. So I can't just insert a row. The index or value sorting is not important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Idea is use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by all possible combinations created by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['Name'].unique(), 
                                  range(1, df['Hour'].max() + 1)], names=['Name','Hour'])
df1 = (df.set_index(['Name','Hour'])
         .reindex(mux)
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
   Name  Hour  Open
0   Bob     1   4.0
1   Bob     2   NaN
2   Bob     3   2.0
3  Jane     1   1.0
4  Jane     2   7.0
5  Jane     3   NaN
```

If use pandas 0.24+ is possible use [Nullable Integer Data Type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['Name','Hour'])
         .reindex(mux).astype('Int64')
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
   Name  Hour  Open
0   Bob     1     4
1   Bob     2   NaN
2   Bob     3     2
3  Jane     1     1
4  Jane     2     7
5  Jane     3   NaN
```

And for replace non exist values to `0` add `fill_value` parameter:

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['Name','Hour'])
         .reindex(mux, fill_value=0)
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
   Name  Hour  Open
0   Bob     1     4
1   Bob     2     0
2   Bob     3     2
3  Jane     1     1
4  Jane     2     7
5  Jane     3     0
```

Comment: as a pandas noob, i would have reached for `df.append` or `concat`. can you expand on why this solution might be preferred over `df.append` or `concat`?

Comment: @RickTeachey - I think yes, this is more general.

Comment: If the OP wants to keep an integer type, then maybe even `.fillna(0).astype({'Open': 'int'})` could be added here

Comment: always forget about the new `fill_value` - thanks for reminding me @jezrael